# How to set value 1 (integer) into an variable inside IF clause in ASP classic?

Tags: asp-classic

I'm currently working on a webpage using ASP Classic.
I have created an If statement, if the company id is equal to 1, then the variable receives a connection.execute.
Else, the variable must receive an fixed value of 1.
For some reason it's not working. I've tried to google the correct syntax for such case, but I haven't been successful... here is the part of the code I have just told you guys about:

```
<%
Dim integrated_code
if SESSION("Company_ID") = 1 Then
    set integrated_code = connection.execute("SELECT TOP 1 ID_BLABLABLA FROM BLABLABLA")
Else
   set integrated_code = 1
End if
%>
```

Comment: You need to use `CInt()` to check the value stored in the `Session` object is an integer. Also the `Set` statement is only for object references.

Comment: You said "it's not working" but you don't describe in what way it's not working, is there an error message, if so what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lose the "set", at least for the simple variable. The other one depends on the nature of "connection".

```
<%
Dim integrated_code
If Session("Company_ID") = 1 Then
    Set integrated_code = connection.execute("...")
Else
    integrated_code = 1
End If
%>
```